# Disable all scons warnings

Tags: python, build, scons

This should be ridiculously simple.

I found the man page here: http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html

Directly from it it says:

```
--warn=all, --warn=no-all     // Enables or disables all warnings.
```

So I type:

```
scons --warn=no-all
```

And I still get a million warnings when building. I must be screwing up something ridiculously simple =\

I get a couple hundred of these before my terminal runs out of history:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

edit: FOUND THE PROBLEM!! It's a C/C++ project so the code I needed was:

```
   env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-Wno-write-strings"])
```

what I had:

```
   env.Append(CFLAGS=["-Wno-write-strings"])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warnings you are getting are coming from your compiler, not from Scons itself. Scons itself doesn't have very many warnings. The `--warn=` switch only applies to Scons.

What you need to do is pass the appropriate compiler flag to your compiler to turn off the warning you don't want. You can do this using the `CCFLAGS` environment value:

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-Wno-write-strings"])
```

`CCFLAGS` applies the line to both C and C++ targets.

The above flag is for Gcc.

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue. Perhaps I'm not building with GCC?

Comment: Only you can tell us what compiler you're using. Also, your environment might not be called `env`.

Comment: I used env = Envrinment() before so env is the right name.

I haven't the slightest clue as to go about finding out which compiler I'm using unfortunately. I'll poke around for a bit to try and find out. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Got it Greg after a day. I was missing a C, I needed env.Append(CCFLAGS=['...']) and I had env.Append(CFLAGS=['...'])